# PhpStorm highlighting Laravel blade incorrectly on Mac? Was ok on old PC

Tags: macos, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade

tl;dr -  My PhpStorm 10 is highlighting my blade code incorrectly: (see screenshot)

Screenshot sample of incorrect highlighting:
[image]

Please help me fix this?

I recently switched away from PC (PhpStorm 9) to Mac (PhpStorm 10.0.2).

I git cloned to the new mac (a Laravel 5.1 project), setup homestead, ok.

But PhpStorm highlights this code as if I've missed an ending semicolon. (see screenshot above - the below is the code that gets highlighted strangely).

```
        @yield('content')

           <!--also the following-->

        @if (Session::has('flash_message'))
            <div>{{ Session::get('flash_message') }}</div>
        @endif
```

This was not an issue on my old PC setup.  AFAIK Laravel's @yield and @if @endif don't need a semicolon, based on [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#template-inheritance).

I've run this code for 4 months from my old PC without issues, and it runs normally on my Mac's Laravel Homestead installation.

I've tried these:

**1.** exported and imported all settings from my old PC's phpstorm to 
        the Mac - it imported my text colors but still highlights wrong on Mac.

**2.** downloaded the Laravel plugin and restarted phpstorm - no change

**3.** confirmed the blade plugin is activated in phpstorm

**4.** tested the same file on my old PC - no issues there in phpstorm 9.

What could be causing this highlighting? What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tinkered around and a solution:

Go to Phpstorm

> Preferences  (on Mac, 'Settings' on PC) >
>   Editor > Colors & Fonts > PHP >
>   PHP Code  > Background

On my Mac the background color was set incorrectly to white (inherited).

**I then unchecked "Use Inherited Attributes" and set it to black. Problem fixed.**

I don't know why this was set to white as on my PC it is set to black.
I had done a phpstorm full settings export from pc, and imported to mac, using the generated settings.jar file so I can't say why this did not import properly. Don't know if something changed between versions 9.0 and 10.0 or whether it got skipped somehow during import.

Comment: It seem that upgrade PHPStorm 9 to 10 has a important modification (eg : indexation) which change deeply the engine of the software. Perhaps open a issue on bugtracker jetbrains for PHPstorm...